# Adding Audio To FLV in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

I have an FLV without sound, and a sound file without video.  Can I combine them using Actionscript?  Where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, here are a couple of possibilities

1/you could use OSMF which gives you the possibility of playing elements in parallel. Check this video for an intro to OSMF

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=129

2/ Otherwise, here's a couple of tutorials about video & sound basics

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=61

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=61

then  you should create a few functions to ensure that when you call play or stop both the video & audio play or stop together. this should be easy to implement after you've watched the tutorials